# how to get data from MySQL DB and set it in HashMap in Java (register/login GUI program)

Tags: java, mysql, dictionary

I am currently working on register/login GUI window and l am trying to store passwords and usernames in MySQL DB. I also want to check if a user with such password exists but l don't know how to get just 1 password and 1 user. I want to save from each row the username and the password inside a HashMap (username -> key| password -> value)

- [This is how my DB looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6fRb.png)
- [This is what rows l want to get in the Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YEI0.png)

How can l set each username and password into a HashMap?

I only can think of this:

```
SELECT username, password 
FROM table
```

I can't continue from here...

Comment: SELECT username, password FROM table WHERE username =: username AND password =:password LIMIT 1

Answer (score 0):

Your usernames should be unique, so to retrieve one pair of username and its corresponding password, you can limit your query by adding `WHERE username=` and append whatever username for which you want to retrieve the username/password pair. After that, storing the fields of the result set in a HashMap is pretty trivial.